# How to query rewards of a specific KT1 account?

Tags: tzscan, query, rpc, api

I want to know, how much rewards a specific KT1 Account earned since cycle 7.

A good Example is the "Rewards Share" Tab of TzScan.
[image: Rewards Share tab]

https://tzscan.io/tz1Tnjaxk6tbAeC2TmMApPh8UsrEVQvhHvx5?default=rewards

This TzScan API call "unexpectedly" delivers the tz1 Manager Rewards.

https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/delegator_rewards_with_details/KT1BNVf6f359fNbokCKMXuKNmpzUy3Nwugyj

But I need the KT1 Rewards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to directly query just the delegator's reward from TzScan API.

But you can easily use [this API call](https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/delegator_rewards_with_details/KT1BNVf6f359fNbokCKMXuKNmpzUy3Nwugyj) with some extra calculations:

```
//This is what the baker got
var total_reward = rewards + extra_rewards - losses;

//This is the delegator's share in the staking balance
var share = balance / staking_balance;

//This is the delegator's reward (without fee, etc) for the selected cycle
var reward = total_reward * share;
```

Also, if you don't need the reward details, you might want to use [this API call](https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/delegator_rewards/KT1BNVf6f359fNbokCKMXuKNmpzUy3Nwugyj).

Comment: I would have to do this for every single cycle since cycle 7, if i understand correct (because the balance from var share = balance / staking_balance changes every cycle)?

Comment: Yep, you’re right. And not only `share` changes from cycle to cycle but also `total_rewards`.